# hashlib md5 doesn't actually turn into md5?

Tags: python, hashlib

I have been using the following code to convert a string into an md5 hash:

```
password = passwd.hexdigest()
```

passwd is supposed to be 'test123' so it is supposedly turning that into an md5 hash.

It gives me the following:

```
6adf97f83acf6453d4a6a4b1070f3754
```

Now when you decrypt that hash, it does not go back to 'test123'.

This is the correct md5 hash that goes back to 'test123':

```
cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5
```

This is the code:

```
passw = request.forms.get('password')
password = hashlib.md5(str(passw)).hexdigest()
```

How can I work this out so it gives me the correct reversable hash?

Comment: What is `passwd.hexdigest`? What do you mean by "*Now when you decrypt that hash, it does not go back to test123*" ?

Comment: `hashlib.md5("test123").hexdigest()` gives me `cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5`..

Comment: @JonClements I edited the original post.

Comment: @alecxe It gives me something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`6adf97f83acf6453d4a6a4b1070f3754` is actually md5 value of "None", so maybe you get something wrong elsewhere.

Let's say you didn't actually get the `passw` from request.forms, and parse the `None` to str(), then gives it to md5().hexdigest(), you'll just get the result.

Comment: @JasonDecastro You could just try to log or print the result of ``request.forms.get('password')``, and if you passed something to ``password`` and get a ``None``, you get problem at this part - and that's a different question than "hashlib md5 doesn't actually turn into md5?"

Comment: @JasonDecastro the code you've posted implies there is no `password` field being sent... try changing to `request.forms['password']` and handling any `KeyError` instead...

Comment: It was returning None. I fixed the problem. Thanks!